# Ansible: What is the correct syntax for a variable within a findall regex

Tags: regex, ansible

I am using Ansible version 2.9.  I want to do a GET, which returns a block of info, regex an ID from that info that corresponds to whatever host I am iterating through at the moment, and then later do things with that ID.

I have the regex working ( https://regex101.com/r/UL7V6r/2 ).  And I confirmed this regex *does* work in the playbook when I input it exactly like in the sample.  But, I need the host name at the end of that regex to be a **variable** matching the host I am iterating through, not a static host name.  Here is the playbook, focused on just getting the regex to work:

```
  gather_facts: no
  vars:
    the_name: "{{ inventory_hostname_short }}"

  tasks:

    - uri:
                  url: http://controller-sample-a1p.someplace.com/restapi/nodes
                  method: GET
                  return_content: yes
      register: nodeId
      delegate_to: 127.0.0.1

    - debug: msg="{{ nodeId.content | regex_findall("(\w+-\w+-\w+-\w+-\w+)..<address>\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+:?\d+?<\/address><name>{{ the_name }}") }}"
      delegate_to: 127.0.0.1

   - debug:
           var: the_name
```

The focus is on the end of that regex, with the variable of "the_name".  As you can see I am trying curly brackets here.  I've tried lots of variations insulting no brackets, single quotes, double quotes, etc.

The results of this play is:

```
ok: [sampleFQDN2.place.com -> 127.0.0.1] => {
    "msg": []
}

TASK [debug] *************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [sampleFQDN2.place.com] => {
    "the_name": "sampleFQDN2"
}
```

Expected result would be for debug msg one to show "FJLEEJ24-3190-49F1-965D-823F63904136" (per the link).

So this suggests to me that the variable is correct (second debug).  And the regex is correct because if I take the variable output of "sampleFQDN2" and plug it in directly, that first debug spits out the right response.  Which leads me to believe I just have not found the right syntax to stick a variable in a regex_findall.

Does anyone know the syntax for this?  Or even if it is possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You never nest Jinja `{{...}}` template markers. Within a Jinja template, if you want to combine a literal string and a variable, you can use the `~` string concatenation operator, like this:

```
    - debug: msg="{{ nodeId.content | regex_findall("(\w+-\w+-\w+-\w+-\w+)..<address>\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+:?\d+?<\/address><name>" ~ the_name) }}"
```

The `~` operator is like `+`, except it will convert arguments into
strings so that you can concatenate numeric values to a string
(writing `"this " + 1` would fail, but `"this " ~ 1` would work).

Or you can use Python string formatting syntax, like this:

```
    - debug: msg="{{ nodeId.content | regex_findall("(\w+-\w+-\w+-\w+-\w+)..<address>\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+:?\d+?<\/address><name>%s" % (the_name)) }}"
```

This syntax uses `printf`-style formatting tokens (`%s` for strings,
`%d` for integers, etc). Or like this:

```
    - debug: msg="{{ nodeId.content | regex_findall("(\w+-\w+-\w+-\w+-\w+)..<address>\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+:?\d+?<\/address><name>{}".format(the_name)) }}"
```

[Here](https://pyformat.info/) is one site that documents Python
string formatting in some detail.

Comment: Tested all 3 answers, all 3 worked.  Most impressive, thanks.